# Paramentro dentro de um if não pega os valores

Tags: javascript

Galera na função estou passado um parametro com idJogo q obtem o id do Jogos, coloco o `console.log(idJogo)` e tenho todos os ids mais sim eu fizer o mesmo dentro dos if quando execute o `console.log()` dar q não foi definido.

```
function atualizaContador(YY, MM, DD, HH, MI, divJogos, idJogo) {
    //alert(saida);
    var SS = 00; //Segundos
    var hoje = new Date(); //Dia
    var diaAtual = hoje.getDate();
    var mesAtual = hoje.getMonth();
    var horaAtual = hoje.getHours();
    var futuro = new Date(YY, MM - 1, DD, HH, MI, SS); //Data limite do contador
    var diaFuturo = futuro.getDate();

    var ss = parseInt((futuro - hoje) / 1000); //Determina a quantidade total de segundos que faltam
    var mm = parseInt(ss / 60); //Determina a quantidade total de minutos que faltam
    var hh = parseInt(mm / 60); //Determina a quantidade total de horas que faltam
    var dd = parseInt(hh / 24); //Determina a quantidade total de dias que faltam

    ss = ss - (mm * 60); //Determina a quantidade de segundos
    mm = mm - (hh * 60); //Determina a quantidade de minutos
    hh = hh - (dd * 24); //Determina a quantidade de horas
    if (ss < 10) {
        ss = '0' + ss;
    }
    if (hh < 10) {
        hh = '0' + hh;
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }

    //O bloco abaixo descreve monta o que vai ser escrito na tela
    var faltam = '';
    //faltam += (dd && dd > 1) ? dd+' dias, ' : (dd==1 ? '1 dia, ' : '');
    faltam += (toString(hh).length) ? hh + ':' : '';
    faltam += (toString(mm).length) ? mm + ':' : '';
    faltam += ss;

    if (dd + hh + mm + ss > 0 && ((dd == 0) && hh < 1)) {
        document.getElementById(divJogos).innerHTML = faltam + ' para encerrar a aposta.';
        setTimeout(function() {
            atualizaContador(YY, MM, DD, HH, MI, divJogos)
        }, 1000);
    } else if (hh <= 0 && mm <= 0) {
        document.getElementById(divJogos).innerHTML = 'Aposta encerrada';
        $.post('funcoes/funcoesForm.php', {
            acao: 'update',
            idJogo: idJogo
        }, function(retorno) {
            alert('Status Atualizado');
        })
    } else if (diaFuturo === diaAtual) {
        document.getElementById(divJogos).innerHTML = 'Hoje' + ' às ' + HH + ':' + MI;
        setTimeout(function() {
            atualizaContador(YY, MM, DD, HH, MI, divJogos)
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(divJogos).innerHTML = DD + '/' + MM + '/' + YY + ' às ' + HH + ':' + MI;
        setTimeout(function() {
            atualizaContador(YY, MM, DD, HH, MI, divJogos)
        }, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: Essa função não está fechada... falta um `}`. Repara que quando chamas assim: `atualizaContador(YY, MM, DD, HH, MI, divJogos)` falta um argumento... o `idJogo` certo?

Comment: Amigo já dei um jeito srsrs consegui fazer